# Disable 10 seconds timeout on BroadcastReceiver. Android Development

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have a IncomingSmsReceiver class that receives a sms message but the problem is it takes a while to receive the text message, I know that the BroadcastReceiver class automatically stop the process if it's listening for more the 10 seconds, is there any way to disable this?

heres my code:

```
public class IncomingSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private ShowDialogInterface callback;


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String messageBody = "no data";
        String messageFrom = "no data";
        for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
            messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            messageFrom = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        }

        if(callback != null) {
            callback.smsDetails(messageFrom, messageBody);
        }
    }
}

public void registerReceiver(ShowDialogInterface receiverCallback) {
    this.callback = receiverCallback;
}

// Show different UI elements to notifying the user of an incoming SMS
public interface ShowDialogInterface {
    void smsDetails(String from, String message);
}
}
```

Here is my debug error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aForV.png)

Best Regards,

Noob Android_dev

Comment: Recommended way is to create a service and let the receiver just send data (the intent) unprocessed to it. Then the service can process the data.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is, exactly, or what you're asking to do. Your `IncomingSmsReceiver` doesn't actually run until a broadcast happens. The amount of time spent "listening" isn't a concern. The 10-seconds limit is for how long `onReceive()` takes to run, if it's on the main thread. Your `onReceive()` will take no where near 10 seconds to run.

Comment: Hello Guys/Gals I attach the debug error on my post, I hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: plz post debug error in text format

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can start service from your BroadcastReceiver and do all job in it. It's a standard way to do such things.